# How to notify Android Widget to redraw

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, remoteview

I have an Android Widget using `RemoteViewsFactory` in order to populate a ListView.

My data source is an asynchronous JSON call which can be done at any time (it's not a push notification). Right now the code is located in `onDataChanged` and looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {

    // Subsequent calls to get the data.
    // Called when the widget onReceive ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE procs.
    newsGetter.updateListFeed(null, new NewsGetter.OnUpdateListFeedFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdateListFeedFinished(VolleyError error) {
            //called when async call has finished. not sure what to call here?
        }
    });

    Log.e(TAG, "******************************** onDataSetChanged PROVIDER");
}
```

Every hour (I've set `updatePeriodMillis` to update every hour) my `AppWidgetProvider` gets a `onReceive` call asking for an update (`ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE`) and as such my above code runs. However, after my code runs and updates `feedItems`, the UI never updates even when scrolling.

So my question is: how do I invalidate the UI and tell it to redraw all the views?

So far I've tried:

```
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_list);
```

But this also calls `onDataChanged` which would cause an infinite loop, so I can't use that.

Comment: have you tried `invalidateViews();`

Comment: @MustansarSaeed That would only be available on a ListView. I'm using a RemoteViewsFactory which means it's a RemoteView, no such call exists.

Comment: Answer was to use LocalBroadcastManager to do it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263508/android-onreceive-not-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to use `LocalBroadcastManager` to send a message from the `RemoteViewsFactory` to the `AppWidgetProvider`. For an example, see here:
[Android onReceive not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263508/android-onreceive-not-called)